# Java's Client / Server has imperfect connection and not working communications

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Client / Server for a Timered Login - My codes are creazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929985/client-server-for-a-timered-login-my-codes-are-creazy)

please, take a look at this CLient Server Programs and help me to let them work. The program should start a timer only after that the Server check the login sent by client and send back an "OK" after a log-in check. Please help me, these codes do something crazy, for example: a second client starts when I click the Client Button "CONNETTI" (CONNECT)... and I don't know why neither how! please help me, thanx!!!

--- CLIENT PROJECT ---

```
enter code here

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Date;


public class Cronometro{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel labelTime;
    private JPanel panelButtons;
    private JButton buttonLogin;
    private JButton buttonLogout;
   JTextField username = new JTextField(15);
   JTextField password = new JTextField(15);
   JTextField telefono = new JTextField(6);
   JLabel status = new JLabel("Server Disconnesso");
   JLabel empty = new JLabel();
   JLabel title = new JLabel ("LudecaLog-In");
   JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel ("Nome Utente: ");
   JLabel passLabel = new JLabel ("Password: ");
   JLabel telLabel = new JLabel ("Telefono: ");
    private Timer timer;
    private long startTime;

    String rigaTesto;
   // DataInputStream in;
    BufferedReader in ;
    DataOutputStream  out;
    Socket clientSocket;

    public Cronometro ()
    {


        frame = new JFrame ("Cronometro");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize (500, 500);

        labelTime = new JLabel ("0:00:00.0");
        labelTime.setFont (new Font ("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 30));
        labelTime.setHorizontalAlignment (JLabel.CENTER);

        buttonLogin = new JButton ("START");
        buttonLogout = new JButton ("STOP");
        buttonLogout.setEnabled (false);

      title.setForeground(Color.blue);
      title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      Font titleFont = new Font("Title", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 50);
      title.setFont(titleFont);

      GridBagConstraints constr = new GridBagConstraints();

        panelButtons = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());

        constr.gridx=0;
      constr.gridy=2;
      panelButtons.add(nameLabel,constr);
        constr.gridx=1;
      constr.gridy=2;
      panelButtons.add(username,constr);
      constr.gridx=0;
      constr.gridy=4;
      panelButtons.add(passLabel,constr);
      constr.gridx=1;
      constr.gridy=4;
      panelButtons.add(password,constr);
      constr.gridx=0;
      constr.gridy=5;
      panelButtons.add(telLabel,constr);
      constr.gridx=1;
      constr.gridy=5;
      telefono.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
      panelButtons.add(telefono,constr);
      constr.gridx=1;
      constr.gridy=8;
      panelButtons.add(empty,constr);
      constr.gridx=1;
      constr.gridy=9;
      panelButtons.add(status,constr);
      constr.gridx=0;
      constr.gridy=10;
        panelButtons.add (buttonLogin,constr);
       constr.gridx=2;
      constr.gridy=10;
       panelButtons.add (buttonLogout,constr);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.add(title,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add (labelTime, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add (panelButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        timer = new Timer (50, new ActionListener () {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                long diffTime = System.currentTimeMillis () - startTime;

                int decSeconds = (int) (diffTime % 1000 / 100);
                int seconds = (int) (diffTime / 1000 % 60);
                int minutes = (int) (diffTime / 60000 % 60);
                int hours = (int) (diffTime / 3600000);

                String s = String.format ("%d:%02d:%02d.%d", hours, minutes,
                                          seconds, decSeconds);

                labelTime.setText(s);

            }
        });



        buttonLogin.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {

            /***************** 1 CONNESSIONE AL SERVER *******/
                      try {
                         clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.42.176",9910);
                         System.out.println("Connessione al Server in atto...");

                         String loginOperatore = new String() ;

                              loginOperatore=(username.getText()+password.getText()+telefono.getText());

                         //apertura stream di input
                          InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                          BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(isr);

                          //apertura stream di output
                          OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                          BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(osw);
                          PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(bw,true);

                          //invio della stringa al server
                          out.println(loginOperatore.toString());
                          status.setText("Connesso al Server, controllo la Login");


                          String confermaLogin = new String();
                          System.out.println(confermaLogin=in.readLine());
                          System.out.println("ciao----->"+(confermaLogin));
                          if(confermaLogin.equals("OK"))
                          {
                             //if (clientSocket != null && out != null && in != null) {
                               Tempo tempo = new Tempo();
                             final Date data = tempo.dataCompleta;
                             startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                timer.start();
                                buttonLogin.setEnabled(false);
                                buttonLogout.setEnabled(true);                      
                             status.setText("<html>Log In Effettuato con Successo! <br>Data e Ora:<br>"+ data+"</html>");

                      // }  
                          }
                          else if (confermaLogin.equals("DATI_ERRATI"))
                          {
                             status.setText("ERRORE!!! Dati di Log-In Errata!!");

                          }



                          //chiusura della socket e degli stream
                          clientSocket.close();
                          in.close();
                          bw.close();
                          out.close();                                

                      }
                      catch (UnknownHostException err)
                      {
                           System.err.println("Errore: probelmi di comunicazione");
                       }
                      catch (IOException err1)
                      {
                           System.err.println("Errore: probelmi di comunicazione");
                       }

                      /******************************** 1 FINE CONNESSIONE AL SERVER *******/
            }
        });

        buttonLogout.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                    timer.stop ();
                    buttonLogin.setEnabled (true);
                    buttonLogout.setEnabled (false);
                  Tempo tempo = new Tempo();
                  final Date data = tempo.dataCompleta;
                  status.setText("<html>Log Out Effettuato con Successo! <br>Data e Ora:<br>"+ data+"</html>");

            }
        });

        frame.setVisible (true);
    }



    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable()
                              {
                                  public void run()
                                  {
                                 new Cronometro();
                              }
                            });
    }
}


import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;


public class Tempo{
          public int ore,minuti,secondi,giorno,mese,anno;
          public long dataMillis;
          public Date dataCompleta = new Date();

         //costruttore di default
         public Tempo(){        

           GregorianCalendar c =new GregorianCalendar();
           dataCompleta=c.getTime();
           dataMillis=c.getTimeInMillis()/* / (24*60*60*1000)*/;
            ore=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minuti=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            secondi=c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            giorno=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mese=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            anno=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);


         }//Tempo
   }//tempo
```

--- SERVER PROJECT ----

```
enter code here

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Date;


public class provaServer{

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panelButtons;
    private JPanel panelSchermiTitolo;

    private JButton buttonConnetti;
    private JButton buttonDisconnetti;
    private JButton buttonSalvaFile;
    private JButton buttonAggiornaSchermi;
    private JButton buttonCreaLogin;
    private TextArea schermoOperatori;
    private TextArea schermoNotifiche;

   JTextField username = new JTextField(15);
   JTextField password = new JTextField(15);
   JTextField telefono = new JTextField(6);
    JLabel status = new JLabel("Server Disconnesso");
   JLabel empty = new JLabel();
   JLabel title = new JLabel ("LudecaLog-In Server");


    String rigaTesto;
   // DataInputStream in;
    BufferedReader in ;
    DataOutputStream  out;





    public provaServer ()
    {


     try {
         Socket clientSocket=null;
        ServerSocket serverSocket=null;
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9910);
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Server: Sono attivo sulla Rete ");
            //serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);

            status.setText("Il Server è adesso Attivo sulla Rete");

            BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            //Stream di output
            DataOutputStream out=new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            String loginOperatore = new String();
            loginOperatore=in.readLine();
            System.out.println("cronServer:---->"+loginOperatore);
            Operatore operatore = new Operatore();
            if(operatore.controllaLogin(loginOperatore)==true)
            {
               out.writeBytes("OK");
            }
            else
            {
               out.writeBytes("DATI_ERRATI");
            }

            System.out.println("Server: Sono attivo sulla Rete ");
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);               
            status.setText("Il Server è adesso Attivo sulla Rete");

         }
         catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1);
            System.out.println("Server: Non riesco ad aprire il socket");
         }



        frame = new JFrame ("CronometroServer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize (500, 500);

        //TEXT AREA
        //labelTime = new JLabel ("0:00:00.0");
        //labelTime.setFont (new Font ("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 30));

        //labelTime.setHorizontalAlignment (JLabel.CENTER);

        buttonSalvaFile = new JButton ("SALVA FILE");
        buttonCreaLogin = new JButton ("CREA LOGIN");
        buttonAggiornaSchermi = new JButton ("AGGIORNA");
        buttonConnetti = new JButton ("CONNETTI");
        buttonDisconnetti = new JButton ("DISCONNETTI");
        //buttonSalvaFile.setEnabled (false);
        //buttonCreaLogin.setEnabled (false);
        //buttonAggiornaSchermi.setEnabled (false);
        //buttonDisconnetti.setEnabled (false);

        schermoOperatori = new TextArea();
        schermoNotifiche = new TextArea();
        schermoOperatori.setEnabled(false);
        schermoNotifiche.setEnabled(false);

      title.setForeground(Color.blue);
      title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      Font titleFont = new Font("Title", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 45);
      title.setFont(titleFont);

      GridBagConstraints constr = new GridBagConstraints();

        panelButtons = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());
        panelSchermiTitolo = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());

      constr.gridx=0;
      constr.gridy=1;
      panelSchermiTitolo.add(title,constr);
      constr.gridx=0;
      constr.gridy=2;
      panelSchermiTitolo.add(schermoOperatori,constr);
      constr.gridx=0;
      constr.gridy=3;
      panelSchermiTitolo.add(schermoNotifiche,constr);
      constr.gridx=0;
      constr.gridy=4;
      panelSchermiTitolo.add(status,constr);
       constr.gridx=2;
      constr.gridy=0;
       panelButtons.add (buttonDisconnetti,constr);
       constr.gridx=3;
      constr.gridy=0;
       panelButtons.add (buttonAggiornaSchermi,constr);
       constr.gridx=4;
      constr.gridy=0;
       panelButtons.add (buttonSalvaFile,constr);
       constr.gridx=5;
       constr.gridy=0;
       panelButtons.add (buttonCreaLogin,constr);


      frame.add(title,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add (panelButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add (panelSchermiTitolo, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        buttonConnetti.addActionListener (new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {


           }
        });

        buttonDisconnetti.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                try {
               clientSocket.close();
                   in.close();
                   out.close(); 
            } catch (IOException e1) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);       
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

       SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable()
                              {
                                  public void run()
                                  {
                                 new provaServer();
                              }
                            });



    }
}


public class Operatore {

   private String identificatoreLogin = new String ();

   public Operatore()
   {
      identificatoreLogin="rafgrav1106";

   }

   public boolean controllaLogin(String loginInserita)
   {

         System.out.println("oper: "+identificatoreLogin);
            System.out.println("oper:" +loginInserita);
      if(loginInserita.equals(identificatoreLogin))
      {
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }

   }

   public String getIdentificatoreLogin() {
      return identificatoreLogin;
   }

   public void setIdentificatoreLogin(String identificatoreLogin)
   {
      this.identificatoreLogin=identificatoreLogin;   
   }


}
```

Comment: Most of the code has nothing to do with the connection.  I suggest you write the most cut down version which demonstrates your issue.

Comment: you should more accurately describe the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake is to mix text and binary stream e.g. writing one but reading the other.

In your case you mix binary writing (server side) with text reading (client side) which is sure to be confusing.  Also you write text correctly on your client but buffer it which is unlikely to be useful as you have to flush it every time to ensure it is sent.

I suggest you use BufferedReader and PrintWriter and as little else as possible.  BTW PrintWriter doesn't throw  IOException which is not ideal, you have to `checkError()` to see if it failed or not. :|

Comment: thank so much, would you think you can correct my mistakes? I can't find a good italian forum to answer me and i'm not so able in english neither to java, it's a log time i dont programm it and they search it for my work. thankx

Comment: You should try fixing your code and let us know what issues you have. I have google translate is decent most of the time. ;)

Comment: i'm trying to fix it since 4 days ago. everything goes good since tried to design the GUI and create the buffer. but at the begining everything worked. not so much iusses, i just need the client to sent the log in to the server, the server receive it and watch if it's the same of the string-login saved in the object Operatore, if it's the same, the server send an OK to the client, and the client starts the timer after the OK. that's all.

Comment: This code would never have worked because on the server you have `out.writeBytes("OK");
` which does not send a new line and on the client you have `confermaLogin=in.readLine());` which waits for a new line, which you never send.

Comment: I suggest you seperate your network and GUI code into seperate classes and test the network classes independantly.

Comment: the network class worked good when i did'nt have the gui. i hade a guy just for client, but server started by eclipse or netbeans

Comment: not so much iusses, i just need the client to sent the log in to the server, the server receive it and watch if it's the same of the string-login saved in the object Operatore, if it's the same, the server send an OK to the client, and the client starts the timer after the OK. that's all. in future i will add an array of Operatore and will create a method to save the Date and te value of the Timer signed in a exel file or extern memory, but it's not my primary problem now. can you give me an help with buffer?

Comment: Yes, use a BufferedReader and PrintWriter like I said.  You are using them in one direction, just not for the return value.

Comment: don't happen to you too that a second server start when you click on CONNETTI ? i have this problem too... it's almost like it' connect just for half and then start the GUI creation in the constructor... i don't know how to explain

Comment: I think you mean that until your client and server connects, your server GUI stops working?  This is because you are using just one thread for everything and the GUI cannot update when it is doing something else like waiting for a connection from the client.

Comment: ---- CLIENT---
                        OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(osw);
                        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(bw,true);

--- SERVER ----
 BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

you mean this? how can i modificate it? rememmber that befor the GUI creation, i tried to do something with both buffer, but my solution simed the one to works, so i did something wrong, please correct me

Comment: Remove the BufferedWriter from the chain.  The BufferedReader is fine.  This is the code which is basically fine.  It's the code for writing from the server which is broken, DONT use DataOutputStream as it's for binary not text.

Comment: loginOperatore=in.readLine(); ...  don't you think that i mistake inserting this line in the constructor? 
i think that it' can't build the object by constructor, because the string of this readline is from an action controled by the botton CONNETTI of the client!! don't you think so? Help me with this please :(

Comment: I don't see a problem with that.  You should be able to fix the threads you use so this is not a problem.

Comment: but i don't use the tread class in this program :(

Comment: If you want your GUI to work all the time, you will have to.

Comment: ok, i will do the best. thank ypu very much mate!!! :-D

Comment: The problem with me "fixing" code is that I will end up re-writing it so it is unreconginsable and you will have no idea what it is doing. ;)